# Salesforce Community - Navigation Menu straight to Record Detail Page

Tags: community, customer-community, experience-cloud, navigation-menu

I have a customer community in which I would like to go from the navigation menu straight to the record detail page and not first to the list page. It makes no sense for me, the user should see only his data in the detail page and not first the list where only his record is available.

I have a object where the data from the user is saved, so the user should see straight his record detail page from the navigation menu. I try it with the site page in navigation menu, but there I can only insert one specially record id in the url and I cannot set up so that every user lands on his own record detail page.

(user can only see his record (sharing set))

Is there a way to accompolish this without coding?

Comment: I found no way to do this without code, even if the special object is the related Contact, since the {!CurrentUser.value} expression support is so limited. Feel free to upvote [this idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V0000015KtMQAU).

Comment: I don't see it necessary outside of Contact case. 

For Contact I think you can use me Preferences page or something like this

Comment: If you want to present related lists for the user's contact you need to be able to get the current user's contact ID in an expression to generate the related list URL, which you cannot. The same could be said for any other object directly related from the User. Hence my idea...